# How to add popup menu in JFrame in netbeans visual editor

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jpopupmenu

I already try to add PopUp menu to JFrame by design in Netbeans visual editor, but it don't work.
Can anybody step by step hint me how to add it?? 
Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is a `JPopupMenu` is not a component that is initially visible or added to a container. So by just dragging and dropping it into the design view frame, will have no affect visually to the design view.

But, if you look at the source code or the navigator, you *will* see the `jPopupMenu` declared as a class member and instantiated in the `initComponents()` method.

I've attempted different things myself, and from what I've tried, it doesn't look like you can design the popup menu in a visual way. You can though, use the Navigator to design it.

[image]

1. From the Navigator, you will see the `jPopupMenu1`. You can add `JMenus` or `JMenuItems` by right-clicking it and selecting `Add from Palette`.
2. You can then add listener to the `JMenuItem` by right clicking the `JMenuItem` from the navigator and slecting `Events -> Actions -> actionPerformed`

To make the `JPopupMenu` appear, you need to add a `MouseListener` to a component, whether it's the frame or another component. For example (to the frame):

1. Select the frame from the Navigator and right-click it and select `Events -> Mouse ->` and you will need to implement both `mousePressed` *and* `mouseReleased`, as different platforms have different popup triggers, Windows being `mouseReleased` and I think Mac is `mousePressed` (don't quote me).
2. Create a method to show the popup menu.

   ```
   private void showPopupMenu(MouseEvent e) {
      jPopupMenu1.show(this, e.getX(), e.getY());
   }
   ```
3. Implement your `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` methods

   ```
   private void formMousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
           showPopupMenu(evt);
       }
   }                                 

   private void formMouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {                                   
       if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
           showPopupMenu(evt);
       }
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: Tnx for your answer but i'm using mac and also implement my mousePressed and mouseReleased methods but not working :(

Comment: Oooh sry :( i had a mistake. it's ok.
mac popup trigger is 'mousePressed()' too :)